# sql pivot multiple columns or c# split and join in datatable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, pivot-table

I have been working on a gymnastics results program in my spare time and I have some scores in a DB an example of the scores table is below,

```
score_id | round | gymnast_no | apparatus_no | SV | bonus | deductions | score
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |   1   |     1      |       1      |12.3|  0.0  |    2.1     | 10.2 
2        |   1   |     1      |       2      |12.3|  0.0  |    2.1     | 10.2
3        |   1   |     1      |       3      |12.3|  0.0  |    2.1     | 10.2
4        |   1   |     2      |       1      |12.3|  0.0  |    2.1     | 10.2 
5        |   1   |     2      |       2      |12.3|  0.0  |    2.1     | 10.2
6        |   1   |     2      |       3      |12.3|  0.0  |    2.1     | 10.2
7        |   1   |     3      |       1      |12.3|  0.0  |    2.1     | 10.2 
8        |   1   |     3      |       2      |12.3|  0.0  |    2.1     | 10.2
9        |   1   |     3      |       3      |12.3|  0.0  |    2.1     | 10.2
```

*Scores aren't important and are just as an example, I have joined on the relevant tables to translate the raw indexes to a more readable state*

```
SELECT g.No ,g.FirstName, g.Surname, g.Club, g.MedalGroup, gymnast_apparatus_score.start_value, apparatus.apparatus_name, gymnast_apparatus_score.score

FROM gymnast g

INNER JOIN gymnast_apparatus_score on gymnast_apparatus_score.gymnast_No = g.No
INNER JOIN apparatus on gymnast_apparatus_score.apparatus_No = apparatus.apparatus_id
INNER JOIN comp_session on comp_session.session_id = gymnast_apparatus_score.Round

WHERE g.Round = 1
```

***I have managed to further change the results to nearly what I am looking for using Pivot, see below***

```
select No, FirstName, Surname, Club, MedalGroup, 
[Bars], DENSE_RANK() over(partition by MedalGroup order by [Bars] desc) as Position, 
[Beam], DENSE_RANK() over(partition by MedalGroup order by [Beam] desc) as Position, 
[Floor], DENSE_RANK() over(partition by MedalGroup order by [Floor] desc) as Position,
[Vault], DENSE_RANK() over(partition by MedalGroup order by [Vault] desc) as Position

from

(select g.No ,g.FirstName, g.Surname, g.Club, g.MedalGroup, apparatus.apparatus_name, gymnast_apparatus_score.score

FROM gymnast g

INNER JOIN gymnast_apparatus_score on gymnast_apparatus_score.gymnast_No = g.No
INNER JOIN apparatus on gymnast_apparatus_score.apparatus_No = apparatus.apparatus_id
INNER JOIN comp_session on comp_session.session_id = gymnast_apparatus_score.Round

WHERE g.Round = 1) gymnastResults
pivot (sum(score) for apparatus_name in ([Bars], [Beam], [Floor], [Vault])) pvtgymnastResults

order by MedalGroup desc
```

**This has got me to this point**
[Current Data outputted to DataGridView in application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d73S.png)

The query is a static query put together very haphazardly in c#, see below

```
qry = "select No, FirstName, Surname, Club, MedalGroup, ";
            foreach (string str in resOQ)
            {
                qry = qry + "[" + str + "], DENSE_RANK() over(partition by MedalGroup order by [" + str + "] desc) as 'Position', ";
            }
            //remove trailing ","
            qry = qry.Remove(qry.Length - 2);

            qry = qry + " from (SELECT g.No, g.FirstName, g.Surname, g.Club, g.MedalGroup, apparatus.apparatus_name, gymnast_apparatus_score.score FROM gymnast g " +
                "INNER JOIN gymnast_apparatus_score on gymnast_apparatus_score.gymnast_No = g.No " +
                "INNER JOIN apparatus on gymnast_apparatus_score.apparatus_No = apparatus.apparatus_id " +
                "INNER JOIN comp_session on comp_session.session_id = gymnast_apparatus_score.Round " +
                "WHERE g.Round = " + session_cb.SelectedValue +
                    ") gymnastResults " +
                    "pivot(sum(score) for apparatus_name in ([";
            foreach (string str in resOQ)
            {
                qry = qry + str + "], [";
            }
            //remove trailing "], ["
            qry = qry.Remove(qry.Length - 4);
            qry = qry + "])) pvtgymnastResults order by MedalGroup desc";
```

I am wanting to either **pivot** the data on another additional column (SV) or achieve my end goal by some easier method however I have yet to find one and my attempts over the past week or so have lead me round in circles. :-(

I would like the results displayed with the gymnast info (name, age, club, etc...) then the apparatus they are entered on to show the **SV, Score, Rank** with the score header to be the name of the ***actual apparatus***... something like the following

```
    gymnast info | Bars SV | Bars score | Bars rank| Floor SV | Floor score | Floor rank| Beam SV | Beam score | Beam rank| Vault SV | Vault score | Vault rank| etc...
```

I have spent so long trying to get there from different angles now I feel I would be better served throwing it out there to the more experienced in the ways of DB tomfoolery and c# mumbojumboism...

**Can it be done** or would I be better off manipulating the results in memory and handling it with c# in the windows application as opposed to building the query, and if it is possible could you please show me how with an explanation as I am somewhat new to pivoting and I would very much like to learn how to manipulate the data as I see fit, possibly using LINQ in the future but the Lambda syntax scares me!

Many thanks for reading this far and thanks in advance.

Comment: Given the prospect of N apparatuses (apparati?) I would suggest manipulating the data in the application layer. Otherwise, you will likely be building the pivot query dynamically (as you have started) to accommodate the various events. Consider that the DataTable.Merge can append missing columns based on matching PKs (e.g. gymnast id) allowing you to build one datatable per apparatus and then loop through Merging them to get your final result.

Comment: I had thought about creating the temporary tables with select into for each of the apparatus, then joined the tables together as I was trying to limit the network traffic back and forth. That was one way, however I would need to use Dynamic SQL for the number of events/apparatus. As it stands right now I think I'll implement the merging of the data tables in c# and approach the more complex queries later on once I start refactoring.